# Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration'

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, pom.xml, swagger-ui, spring-boot-maven-plugin

Just learning how maven and spring boot works so i've been practicing a little bit by doing simple projects. But i've run into an issue of my swagger-ui.html giving me an error of 404 not found.

What i've added in my pom.xml for swagger-ui.

`

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
   <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.0-M4</version>
</dependency>
```

`

My entire project code is available [here](https://github.com/aakhoja/restful-web-services)

Doing little bit of google search I found some solutions that haven't helped me with my project yet.

Things i've added :

@EnableMvc
@Configuration

in my main controller class. After adding these two annotations, my error displayed a different error. Pasting below :

`Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0;`

I've also tried added numerous other dependencies like

`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui need springboot 3.0+

Comment: would happen to have any resource or documentation i can enable swagger in my project with springboot 2.7.5? 
`<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
   <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.0-M6</version>
  </dependency> `

`<dependency>-->
<!--   <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>-->
<!--   <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>-->
<!--   <version>3.0.0</version>-->
<!--  </dependency>-->`

I've tried these 2 as well and i'm still getting error.

Answer (score 0):

Is your jdk version 17 because I see that it is configured in your `pom.xml` file

```
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: Yes java version is 17 and spring boot is 2.7.5

Answer (score 0):

@DingHao was correct as you need springboot 3.0+ to run webmvc-ui. I was looking for way to enable swagger with my current version of spring(2.7.5) but then i decided to upgrade springboot to 3.0.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

This following code upgraded my springboot from 2.7.5 to springboot 3.0.0-M4. After recompiling with maven, i'm successfully able to access localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html.

My updated code project can be found [here](https://github.com/aakhoja/restful-web-services)

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same issue, when I check my pom.xml I see that, I have using spring boot and spring dependences mixing and some are duplicate.
After removing that my app running fine.

I have pasted my error below

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2ClientConfiguration$OAuth2ClientWebMvcSecurityConfiguration':
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setClientRegistrationRepository' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'clientRegistrationRepository'
defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/servlet/OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration.class]:
Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository]: Factory method 'clientRegistrationRepository'
threw exception with message: Unable to resolve Configuration with the provided Issuer of